# google app engine : how to logout of appcfg from cmd

Tags: google-app-engine, cmd

How to logout from the appcfg in cmd?

I have two seperate GAE accounts, and each account have 1 project, now i ran a vacuum_indexes commond on a project with account 1 in cmd, it asked me for credentials for account 1 and i was done.

Now, i have to run the same vaccum_indexes command for another project in the account 2, now appcfg is not asking me the credentials & using the credentials for the account 1, which ends up with the error saying appid not found or Bad request

Does any one have any idea where cmd saves the credentials?

Is their a way to logout from a appcfg ?

I have no clue..

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Dhiraj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `--no_cookies` to your request. For example:

```
--no_cookies vaccum_indexes myapp
```

Or you can specify your email account in a request:

```
--email=me@myemail.com vaccum_indexes myapp
```